# Проблема с атрибутами data-

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Есть сайт на WP с модальными окнами, и выводятся они таким образом:

```
<a data-options='{"touch" : false}' data-fancybox="" data-src="#modal__member_1" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

Проблема в том, что в какой-то момент окна перестали работать, и сейчас в исходном коде я увидел, что атрибуты data- неправильно выводятся, а именно:

```
<a data="-" options="{"touch" : false}" fancybox="" src="#modal__member_1" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

В чем может быть проблема? В самом php файле код введен верно (вар 1), а в самом браузере нет (вар 2)

Comment: А как выводится код в php файле?

Comment: В вар.1 написал

Comment: Нет. Раз не поняли вопроса - киньте метод полностью где эта строка есть

Comment: <a class="team__img" href="javascript:;" data-fancybox="" data-options='{"touch" : false}' data-src="#modal__member_<?php the_ID(); ?>"  style="background: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>') center no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

Comment: Но похоже проблема в хостинге, тк как на локалке у меня работает хорошо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в стороннем плагине [Remove Redundant Links](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-redundant-links/), который давал такие сбои